# Binding class member functions for boost::signals2

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-signals2, stdbind

I have used std::bind to create a lambda involving a class member function but boost::signals2 won't accept it.

I have a class `Cut` which I would like to inform when there is a new `Event` to look at by calling `void Cut::newEvent(Event& e)`.

I created a lambda binding to an instance of Cut and this works as expected when I pass it an Event. (The code compiles and the output is "Registered new event".)

However when I try to connect this lambda to an instance of `boost::signals2::signal<void(Event&)>` it complains with the message:

`error: 'f' cannot be used as a function`

which is odd because I can use it as a function in main(). ( I get the same result if I use `std::function<void(Event&)>` instead of auto.

Is it possible to make this work? Why doesn't it currently work?

This is relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

//Dummy event class
struct Event
{ int val; };

typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (Event&) >
EventBroadcaster;

//Class I want to notified of new events
class Cut
{
    public:
        void newEvent( Event& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Registered new event" << std::endl;
            fResult = true;
        }

        bool check() const
        { return fResult; }

    private:
        bool fResult;
};

int main()
{

    Cut c{};

    //Lambda to call newEvent on c
    auto f =
        std::bind( &Cut::newEvent, &c,
                std::placeholders::_1) ;

    Event e{};
    f(e); //works

    EventBroadcaster eb;
    eb.connect(&f); //doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
eb.connect(f);
```

since `f` is callable function object, but `&f` is not callable.

Comment: Argh! I was convinced I had tried all the variations like that. Thanks!